# Запятая в стихотворении А. С. Пушкина «Простите, верные дубравы!…»

Tags: пунктуация, пушкин

Подскажите, чем обусловлена запятая перед союзом **И** в пушкинском стихотворении:

*Простите, верные дубравы!

Прости, беспечный мир полей,

**И** легкокрылые забавы

Столь быстро улетевших дней!*

[**Простите, верные дубравы!..**](http://www.friends-partners.org/friends/literature/19century/pushkin/forgive.html(opt,mozilla,mac,russian,koi8,new))

Comment: Вот интересное обсуждение: https://rus-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=10962

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта запятая в данном случае отделяет обращение "беспечный мир полей". Автор просит простить "беспечный мир полей" (что?) "легкокрылые забавы". "И" выступает как усилительная частица.

Comment: Формально верно, но... Пушкин в этом стихотворении, используя метонимию, просит у своих друзей прощения за то, что **оставляет** их. И вдруг он просит прощения еще и за некие "забавы"? Как-то не вписыватся это в общий тон стихотворения. Прослушал в ютубе записи разных чтецов. Ничего подобного там и в помине нет.

Answer (score 2):

Мое понимание таково. Автор просит прощения у "беспечного мира полей" и у "легкокрылых забав". При этом "прости" грамматически не может быть отнесено к "легкокрылым забавам", так как не согласуется с ними в числе. Поэтому рассматривать *и* как союз неверно. Слова "и легкокрылые забавы столь быстро улетевших дней" нужно рассматривать как отдельное, **неполное**, предложение. (В полном варианте оно бы выглядело примерно так: "Простите и вы, легкокрылые забавы столь быстро улетевших дней!".) Формально рассуждая, следовало бы поставить восклицательный знак (или точку) перед *и*. Но тогда интонационно отрывок читался бы по-другому, потерял бы свою "музыку". Таким образом, *и* в данном случае не союз, а услилительная частица, а запятая разделяет два предложения. Повторюсь, это мое мнение, возможно, профессионалы меня поправят.

Дополнение 1.

Забавно. Оказывается, задание расставить знаки препинания в этом стихотворении содержится в де­монстра­ци­он­ной вер­сии ЕГЭ—2017 по рус­ско­му языку. При этом объяснение дается простое: обращение *беспечный мир полей* выделяется запятыми. Никак не объясняется роль последующего *и* и всего, что идет за ним. Неужели составители не нашли более "чистого" примера?

Дополнение 2.

У Валгиной есть глава "[ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНЫЕ КОНСТРУКЦИИ](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook089/01/part-037.htm)" (Валгина Н.С.
Синтаксис современного русского языка). Очень похоже на то, что вторую часть фразы (И легкокрылые забавы//Столь быстро улетевших дней) нужно рассматривать именно как присоединительную конструкцию. Сочинительный союз *и* употреблен в присоединительном значении. Валгина пишет: "При союзном присоединении обычно употребляется запятая: Перед вами люди, имеющие в городе власть, и не малую (Н. И.).".

И еще. Вспомнилось стихотворение Лермонтова "Прощай, немытая Россия". Разве в нем не то же явление:

Прощай, немытая Россия,
Страна рабов, страна господ,
И вы, мундиры голубые,
И ты, им преданный народ.

Comment: Это демоверсия "Незнайки", на официальном сайте "Фипи" ничего такого нет.